# Regex to remove the letter H and any digits following it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Please assist with the proper regular expression in PHP. I have a string (*linear format chemical formula*), in which I want to replace letter '**H**' (or) letter '**H**' followed by digits.

For example:

```
CH3NO+       -> CNO+
C12H17ClN4OS -> C12ClN4OS
CNO3         -> CNO3
H2O          -> O
CHO          -> CO
```

Comment: Replace, `H\d+` by empty space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$newVariable = preg_replace('~H\d*~', '', $yourVariable);
```

The `\d*` means it will match if there are 0 or more matching digits.

Answer (score 1):

please use this it will solve your purpose.

```
<?php
$test = "CH3NO+";
echo preg_replace("/H\d+/i","",$test);
?>
```

Comment: I removed *"please mark answer correct when you are done."* in your [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34647473/1). Please don't do that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok, i just added it earlier because sometime people dont mark it correct and it may not help who will follow this question or anybody who is looking for the similar solution.

Comment: that could be posted under their question as a comment after a while if there is no activity from the OP. I understand how you feel, but there's hardly anything we can do, other than post a comment and not be part of an answer.

Comment: i agree, @Fred-ii- will follow as you suggested, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. The OP's track record is good and accepts answers, so I'm sure they'll either accept (or upvote) if they think your answer works. Quick (pro) tip: Always check a person's other questions first. If they haven't accepted any answers or is in poor standings, then giving them a slight nudge about it could/may help ;-)

Comment: This won't meet OPs requirements; `I want to replace letter 'H' (or) letter 'H' followed by digits` you need to make the `\d` optional with the `*` quantifier. For a failing demo, https://eval.in/498542.